# Weird behaviour than animating lines with rgl and rglwidget

Tags: r, animation, 3d, markdown

I am trying to follow help and Internet examples to create a very simple animation of a 3d-line in R. This is just a test and my final goal is to use this functionality to visually verify results of some geometrical transformations on 3d-movement data that I am analysing.  So basically I need nothing more than a ‘3d-player’ interface that allows for usual interaction (rotation, zoom, play, stop, slide).

I figured out that rgl package does the job and I am able to use it for the sphere/points animation. But now I need to use it on lines and I get very strange results. In the example below there are 4 points and two lines (cyan and red) that connect the same points but the red line is for some reason in the ‘wrong’ place. The animation doesn’t make sense neither. Now, I am thinking may be it is impossible to do >> to animate more than one vertex with more than one attribute? But I don’t see this in documentation and obviously it is possible because line is animated! I spent quite a long time trying to figure out what is going on and will appreciate any help/advise/directions. many thanks

Ps: Tthe code below is a chunk in the markdown file and I am using Rstudio.

```r
require(rgl)
require(rglwidget)
p11=c(0,0,0)
p21=c(50,50,0)
p12=c(50,0,0)
p22=c(10,50,50)

saveopts <- options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
did=list()
did[[1]]=plot3d(rbind(p11,p21,p12,p22), type="s", alpha = 1, lwd = 5, col = c('brown','darkgreen','orange','green'))
did[[2]]=spheres3d(c(100,100,100), alpha = 1, lwd = 5, col = "blue",radius=2)
did[[3]]=lines3d(rbind(p11,p21),lwd=8, col='cyan',alpha=.9)
did[[4]]=planes3d(0, 0, 1, 0, alpha=.4, col='green')
did[[5]]=lines3d(rbind(p11,p21),lwd=2, col='red')
aspect3d(1, 1, 1)
did[[6]]=grid3d(c("x-", "z-"),at = NULL,col = "gray",lwd = .5,lty = 1,n = 5)
sceneT = rglwidget(elementId = "plot3dT",width=500, height=300) #%>%
rgl.ids()
rgl.attrib(id=did[[3]],attrib = c(1:length(did[[3]])))

playwidget(sceneT,list(
  vertexControl(values = rbind(c(0,0,0,0,0,0),c(50,50,50,50,50,50)),
             vertices = 1:6, attributes = "z", objid = did[[4]], param = 1:2,interp =T),
  vertexControl(values = r1,
             vertices = 1:2, attributes = c('x',"y","z",'x',"y","z"), objid = did[[5]], param = 1:2,interp =T)),
  start = 1, stop = 2, step = .1, precision = 3)
options(saveopts)
```

Comment: The markdown tag is for the text formatting syntax. Are you sure is this the markdown you want to tag?